How do I deploy a React app to my Wordpress site?
I am new to React and trying to add my React site to a server so that I can test out a php form processing script. I have run the npm run build command and uploaded the resulting 'dist' folder to the server folder that can display static html files.
When I try to navigate to the new URL I am presented with this error in the console -

Looking at the error message it would seem that the browser is looking for the assets folder in the wrong place and the /dist/ folder should be added before it.
It looks like the initial index.html page is being loaded as the title reflects that, other than that the screen is blank.
Some more info - I am loading the site up to a URL containing a Wordpress site, so am adding the dist files to the public_html folder.
I should perhaps add that I used npx create-vite to create the app as opposed to npx create-react-app
Any assistance would be much appreciated :)

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

You must redefine the path of the /static files, in this case you have to change it in the index.html file, according to the path of the folder where your application is located on the server.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you want to embed your React app on a page of a WordPress website I suggest you use iframe because WordPress renders php codes with webserver tools like apache2 or nginx. This blog must be helpful:
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-embed-a-react-app-inside-a-wordpress-website-923e0af0ea00
Also, you can this extension that I found for you (I had not tested it and just saw a demo about it):
https://wordpress.org/plugins/reactpress/
So the next way
If you want to just deploy your react app as a static website in your host just make a directory in the public_html folder and put static files of react build in it (point: sometimes depends on your code base the react static build depends on the domain and path on the web server of target deployment server or host and you must to set the domain and path in config before build or you can just handle routes of react in htaccess file)
This link is helpful for you:
https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6
(careful in adding the htaccess file in the level file directory to not cause any harm to your WordPress website)
Be happy :)

suggesting an iframe without more details is not recommended because there is now lots of other ways of doing the same with code on back end or front end.
